# How to insert double letters

Tags: python, string, insert

So I am trying to figure some of these intricasies of python out just for shiggles now and I am trying to insert stuff into my strings.  I want to return a copy of the string all of the set letters doubled.  My letters are `l` `m` `n` `q` `t`

so my output for money would look like mmonney

This is code from different attempt in which I stripped out letters, I am trying to figure how to change this so I double the letters in my list.  any suggestions?

```
def double(str):
  letters = ('l', 'm', 'n', 'q', 't')
  for char in str:
    if c.lower() in letters:
      str = str.replace(c,"")
    return str
```

Comment: Your code is not executable. Is that `if char.lower() in letters:`?

Answer (score 1):

Note that with so many str replaces it's not going to make your function very scalable.

```
def double(word):
    letters = ('l', 'm', 'n', 'q', 't')
    return "".join([p*2 if p in letters else p for p in word])
```

Generally string modification operations in python (and quite a few other languages are  slow) because strings are immutable. You are actually making a completely new string from scratch every time you do your replace call.

On the other hand the approach given here is dealing with two lists. Appending to a list is a fast operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just traverse the string and add the character twice as you go.

```
def double(str):
    new_str = ""
    letters = ('l', 'm', 'n', 'q', 't')

    for c in str:
        if c.lower() in letters:
            new_str += c + c

    return new_str

print(double("money"))
```

Comment: The OP said he wanted to double on certain characters. Not every character.

Answer (score 0):

**Method1:**

When you iterate over your string in for loop, the loop iteration is limited to the initial length of the string. So when you try to replace with the character duplicate, the trailing character will be ignored.

Therefore, you can have a new_string in which the character is appended according to your condition!

```
def double(str):
  letters = ('l', 'm', 'n', 'q', 't')
  new_str=''
  for c in str:
    if c.lower() in letters:
      new_str += c
    new_str+=c
  return new_str
print double('money')
```

**Method2:**

You can also use **regex** to makes things simpler.

Join your tuple to form a string and re.sub(regex_pattern,substitution_string,your_string) will substitute the matched regex group with the value given as second parameter! (`\1` is used to get the matched group)

```
st='money'
letters = ('l', 'm', 'n', 'q', 't')
import re
print re.sub('(%s)'%'|'.join(letters),'\\1\\1',st)
```

Output:

```
mmonney
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use `str` as variable name.
[`str` is builtin class in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

try this code

```
_string = "money" # example


def double(string):
    letters = ('l', 'm', 'n', 'q', 't')
    result = list()
    for s in string:
        if s in letters:
            result.append(s.lower() * 2)
        else:
            result.append(s.lower())
    return "".join(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print double(_string)
```

output

```
mmonney
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def doub(inputStr):
   specialChars = ['l','m','n','q','t']
   outputStr = ""
   for i in inputStr:
       if i in specialChars:
          outputStr = outputStr + i + i
       else:
          outputStr = outputStr + i
   return outputStr

print doub("aldamnasamnahoqtk")
```